# Coerce Logical to Numeric in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am creating a new column in PowerBI and would like to return a column with 1s or 0s depending on whether a logical condition is true or false. I would have expected the following to work (as it is similar to type coercion in Excel and other languages)

```
= 1*([Value] < [Threshold])
```

However, it returns an error:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator * to types Number and Logical.
Details:
    Operator=*
    Left=1
    Right=TRUE
```

I have got the result I want by returning a logical value and then manually converting the type, however this seems inefficient. How would the above be accomplished with just a formula?

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding the column using DAX, then you can use the `INT` function:

```
= INT ( [Value] < [Threshold] )
```

If you're using M (Power Query) then you can use the `Number.From` function:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "My Column", each Number.From([Value] < [Threshold]), Int64.Type)
```